# How to migrate .RESX file when changing .NET Framework

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

How to migrate .RESX file when changing .NET Framework...

I was changing the .NET framework from 4.0 to 3.5 (because of an incompatbility we discovered in a third party dll) and everything went fine except some .RESX file got messed up. I was starting to fix them manually but is there some tool I can use for this? Or how do you guys do it?

Comment: There shouldn't be any problem migrating from 3.5 to 4.0 in regards of resource files. What did that file contain and what did mess up?

Comment: @Svarog, not true. Most of the entries in RESX files will reference System DLLs with version = 2.0 when targeting .NET 3.5. When targeting .NET 4.0 they will ALL reference same DLLs but with version = 4.0. Therein lies the problem. You need to manually change those one by one as well as any issues that might arise (see my answer below)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same as "impr0t" (do a global replace) but generally you will have this problem with RESX files: "Can not load assembly ... or one of its dependencies. Attempt to load a program with an invalid structure" and it will point to something like this in your RESX file:

```
<metadata name="icons_20.TrayLocation" type="System.Drawing.Point, System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
    <value>115, 17</value>
 </metadata>
 <data name="icons_20.ImageStream" mimetype="application/x-microsoft.net.object.binary.base64">
    <value>     AAEAAAD/////AQAAAAAAAAAMAgAAAFdTeXN0ZW0uV2luZG93cy5Gb3JtcywgVmVyc2lvbj00LjAuMC4w        LCBDdWx0dXJlPW5ldXRyYWwsIFB1YmxpY0tleVRva2VuPWI3N2E1YzU2MTkzNGUwODkFAQAAACZTeXN0
...
...
...     AQEB7wL/BwABeAEBAeAJAAFwAQAB4AkAAWABAAFgCQABQAEAAWALAAEgCwABIDsAASAJAAFAAQABIAkA
AUABAAEgCQABYAEAAWAJAAFwAQAB4AkAAXgBAQHgCQABfAEHAeALAAEPAv/3AAs=
</value>
 </data>
```

so the fix is described here:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/532584/error-when-compiling-resx-file-seems-related-to-beta2-bug-5252020

from that site:

> Workaround
>
> 1. Open Form in Designer and make needed GUI changes. Close designer and save
> 2. Compile project and receive RESX compile error (only forms with Imagelist should have this problem)
> 3. Double-click resx compile error to open resx file.
> 4. Scroll to top of imagestream.
> 5. Edit the top line of the Image stream: AAEAAAD/////AQAAAAAAAAAMAgAAAFdTeXN0ZW0uV2luZG93cy5Gb3JtcywgVmVyc2lvbj00LjAuMC4w
>      TO
>      AAEAAAD/////AQAAAAAAAAAMAgAAAFdTeXN0ZW0uV2luZG93cy5Gb3JtcywgVmVyc2lvbj0yLjAuMC4w
> 6. Close and save resx file and recompile.
>
> **NOTE: the only difference are the characters at end "j00LjAuMC4w' to "j0yLjAuMC4w"

Answer (score 4):

I've usually just gone through and edited the xml.

.NET 4.0

```
<value>System.Resources.ResXResourceReader, System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>
```

.NET 2.0

```
<value>System.Resources.ResXResourceReader, System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>
```

It doesn't take too long to do if you just do a find & replace.  Everything seems to work out fine on recompile.

Comment: Yup, that's what I generally do but this time I actually got errors when doing it (see my answer) to this question. Was just wondering if there was some tool we were supposed to use instead of doing it manually like we are doing...